# Save html result to a txt or html file

Tags: r

I have a variable with html code.

Here what the code variable outpout in R console:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I try to save the content into a txt file

```
 write.table(code, file='C:/Users/Desktop/code_result.txt')
```

But it stacks with this error:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  c("cannot coerce class \"c(\"HTMLInternalDocument\", \"HTMLInternalDocument\", \"XMLInternalDocument\", \" to a data.frame", "cannot coerce class \"\"XMLAbstractDocument\")\" to a data.frame")
```

Comment: Use `saveXML` instead of `write.table`. Or provide a reproducible example, otherwise it will be a guessing game.

Comment: @Narendra the code is html code in this format `<html> <head> <h3> Title </h3> </head> <body> </body> </html>`

Comment: @lukeA saveXML works!

Comment: @lukeA What package does `saveXML()` come from? Or is `saveXML` itself the package name?

Answer (score 9):

Here is a simple solution (although I prefer using package XML as suggested in the comments to your question):

```
code <- "<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <body>

  <h1>My First Heading</h1>

  <p>My first paragraph.</p>

  </body>
</html>"
```

NOTE: if you already have an object containing the text above,
you can convert it to a character string so the code below applies:

```
code <- paste(as.character(code), collapse = "\n")

write.table(code, 
            file='C:/Users/dsargsy/Desktop/code_result.html', 
            quote = FALSE,
            col.names = FALSE,
            row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Davit this code from 4 years completely saved my week. Cheers dude!

Answer (score 5):

One option is `saveXML` and another is `sink()`:

```
pacman::p_load(scrapeR) # or require() or library()
f = system.file("exampleData", "mtcars.xml", package="XML")
doc = xmlTreeParse(f, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
sink("your.file.txt")
doc
sink()
```

Answer (score 2):

very comfortable package for all read/write actions is the rio package.

```
library(rio)
export(html_code,
       file="html_code_result.html",
       format="html"
      )
```

in this syntax, the rio::export() function supports many other formats,
including

- excel
- matlab
- spss
- json

and many more.
It's also very fast!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution using only base would have to be:

```
writeLines(text = code, con = 'C:/Users/Desktop/code_result.txt')
```